# Writing a single page client-side only webpage

Tags: javascript

I'm considering to try out an idea, mostly for fun, and my question is if this is reasonable and if there are any libraries or frameworks that could make this experiment a little easier.

So, the idea: Basically it is to write a new UI for a website I've developed, but doing it with client-side code only. I can read/write data using ajax, since my existing website has an API that allows me to perform all kinds of queries. This allows me to use JavaScript for the whole thing and theoretically put all of the code in a single file.

Obviously there are limitations to circumvent; bookmarking, page refreshing, the back-button etc. But these limitations are what makes it interesting, right? :) I'm not so worried about search engine indexing, since one has to be logged in to use the site anyway.

The site itself is not overly complex, but it is not simple either. There are four different levels of users, multiple languages and quite a lot of data to be presented.

Is this a bad idea? If so, why would you advice against it? And do you know of any JavaScript frameworks or libraries that could make this easier? (And no, I'm not looking for an abstraction like Google Web Toolkit; I would like something purely JavaScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my coworkers did this. A nice feature of this concept was that you don't have a ton of POSTS whenever the user 'changes pages', since they are actually not ever changing a page until they submit their data for the final time. He did this for product registration software, which was nice. Our servers were only taking a hit when the user initially requested the page, and then when they submitted it.

The major, MAJOR downside to this concept is that most web developers are not expecting this. My coworker (and you) have a cool idea - but unless it is well implemented, with comments, 100% valid HTML, and a host of other good design principles in place, it can be confusing since most web developers have basically never seen this done before. His site was a nightmare to work with, as he did not actually know what engineering web software meant, and it was all slapped together. My organization never pursued this (potentially useful) idea because his implementation was so poor.

So, when I looked at this idea here were the trade-off I came up with:

1.) You cannot require any server-side interaction during intermediate pages.
2.) The initial page loading is longer, but there are no intermediate page requests (better optimization).
3.) This is vastly different than anything anyone usually does, which means you need to be especially careful with documentation.
4.) This design concept facilitates totally stand-alone web software to be easily deployed without the web. 
5.) You might be increasing complexity for avoiding page loads, but maybe not. I'm not sure.

All together, I think it just depends on what you want to accomplish. My coworker really just wanted to see if he could do it, which he could. However, how he did it was really pretty bad, to the point where everyone else connected his poor implementation with a poor idea it was fairly sad.

Mostly, I think if you follow good web design practices this wouldn't be too bad of a thing to pursue. What are your goals though?

I'm sorry I couldn't directly answer all of your questions. I hope my experiences are still helpful in answering if I think it is a bad idea or not.

-Brian J. Stinar-

Comment: Great points, useful answer! I actually did think about how it would look to other developers (it was one of the reasons I asked about it here of course). Nice to hear some thoughts about it.

Answer (score 2):

[SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/what-is-sproutcore/) is one of the best out there when it comes to really being built from the ground up for single-page, potentially complex applications. Unlike some others like [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) or [Cappucino](http://cappuccino.org/), SproutCore is really about using JavaScript directly. They aren't the only one though. You might also want to look at [JavaScriptMVC](http://www.javascriptmvc.com/) and [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/).

Personally, I've built an extremely large and complex single-page application using JavaScript. It is currently around 100,000 lines (including comments/whitespace). To give a sense of scale, jQuery is around 6,000. To reach that size, I built my own framework, build tools etc. and it is extremely maintainable. You're asking if it can work, and I can tell you that it does, but you do need a little infrastructure if you're looking at doing something big. (BTW, there's a lot of lazy loading - its not 100,000 lines all at once!)

I also wouldn't really recommend this method for anything other than a web application. As pointed out, its still difficult for SEO, and may be strange for some users.

Comment: SproutCore looks promising, I'll dig into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/)

Answer (score 0):

I did my site like that in jquery, backed by spring mvc 3. For me it works fine and you have a lightweight, flashy feling while on it.
If you have time to dig in javascript seriously... it is really good exercise.
The only thing I really need to add is SEO, since spiders see only intial html. If it is important for you, i think backend static files and sitemap would be good enough solution.

Comment: By the way, address is www.milanaleksic.net if you want to get an idea how it looks - still under devel. though

Comment: Feels a little like flash, yeah. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I found something very light-weight that provides the basic needed functionally without forcing you into a whole framework. It's called Sammy and is inspired by Ruby's Sinatra: http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/

Very recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: code the same in Java. Take a look to [ItsNat](http://www.itsnat.org)

Think in JavaScript but code the same in Java in server with the same DOM APIs, in server is way easier to manage your application without custom client/bridges because UI and data are together.

Regarding SEO, bookmarking etc in single page there are solutions, take a look to the [Single Page Interface Manifesto](http://itsnat.sourceforge.net/php/spim/spi_manifesto_en.php)